# PHP | GD Functions or Curl? Which is better in terms of memory util and load time?

Tags: php, curl, gd

I am using both GD and Curl(one or other) for downloading remote jpeg images to my server. I just want a quick suggestion on which method to use? Which method takes less system resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get load time try to create complex image with both of them (GD and CURL), set microtime at the start of each operation and calculate time-difference at the end. Just do a test at your own.

About memory usage (system resources), I'm not so sure, but I think there's no such big difference.

For me personally, GD and Curl are equal.